# Sending binary data with the Restlet client

Tags: java, http, rest, restlet, put

I'm trying to send a byte[] (using PUT) with Restlet but I can't find any info on how to do it. My code looks like this:

```
Request request = new Request(Method.PUT, url);
request.setEntity( WHAT DO I PUT HERE?, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
```

I had expected to find something along the lines of ByteArrayRepresentation, just like there's a JsonRepresentation and a a StringRepresentation but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you want to use an [InputRepresentation](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.1/api/org/restlet/resource/InputRepresentation.html), like so:

```
Representation representation = new InputRepresentation(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
request.setEntity(representation);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with restlet, but one way to do it would be to base64 encode the data. Then you could handle it like a regular string.

Comment: Thanks Emil but that is not efficient enough in this case. This code will be sending large amounts of data so having to send 33% more data is not an option.

Comment: Yeah, kinda figured. Thought I'd mention it anyway, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try subclassing `WritableRepresentation` that is especially designed for large representations